# maven dependency version issue

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, maven-dependency

Am using a kafka-client dependency in my project abc-bus-api. The version is 2.1.0. See below.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

[image]

Now this above project is a dependency in another project abc-lib. Here i see a different kafka-client version than what i have specified in my abc-bus-api. See below.

[image]

maven tree in STS (for kafka):

[image]

Any guess what am doing wrong here.

Comment: Multiple dependencies seem to be pulling in `kafka-clients` as a dependency, and the 1.x/2.x is likely to be a problem. Try `mvn dependency:tree`.

Comment: I updated my question. You can see the tree view in STS.

Comment: Have you checked the parent module of your abc-bus-api? From "managed from 2.1.0", I think it has a <dependencyManagment> to define the version for all children modules.

Comment: Looks like your abc-bus-api project has another dependency which depends on the older version of kafka-clients. You can verify this based on your effective pom or dependency tree for your project. 

In addition you can check this link: https://dzone.com/articles/solving-dependency-conflicts-in-maven. I think it might help you.

Comment: thanks for the direction. It was due to abc-lib. It has "spring-boot-dependencies" dependency(version 2.0.5.RELEASE) in dependency management and this uses a old version of kafka. Upgrading this solved it. Appreciate your help.  @MageXellos.